# How can i use my javascript gallery 2 times with other images on the same page?

Tags: javascript, gallery

I cannot duplicate this gallery to use it on the same page with other images. Can someone please tell me how I can do it? I am new to Javascript and I can't find any solution. Thanks a lot !

HTML

```
    <div id="gallery-container" >

        <div id="galerie"></div>
        <div id="afisare"></div>
                      

       </div>       

       </div>


JS

const galerie_div= document.getElementById("galerie");        
const test = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
const img= document.createElement('IMG');

// container
const bgPoze = document.getElementById("poze");

const  afisare= document.getElementById("afisare");
// bg poze mici

const divPoze = document.getElementById('poze');
bgPoze.style.backgroundColor ="#56423e";


for(var i=1; i<6; i++){ 

    
    
    const img= document.createElement('IMG');
    
    divPoze.appendChild(img);

    // creare clasa la img

    img.classList.add('test');

    
    img.setAttribute('src', "assets/images/gal1tumb/interioare" + i + ".webp");

    img.setAttribute("onclick","bg("+i+")");

    img.style.maxWidth="100%";



    // adaugare clasa up

    img.addEventListener ('click', function(z){

        const scale = z.target;

        scale.classList.toggle('up');



});
```

I have tried to use switch case but i have not succeeded .